# GKScene SpriteKit error: [SKScene setEntities:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, entities, gameplay-kit

I have a code which imports GameplayKit fine, and I can get the GKScene like this:

```
GKScene * scene = [GKScene sceneWithFileNamed:@"GameScene1"];
```

Then, I am getting this to `GameScene` which extends a normal `SKScene` like this:

```
GameScene1 * scene1 = (GameScene1 *)scene.rootNode;
```

I then get an error  `[SKScene setEntities:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`
when I try to fetch the entities like this:

```
scene1.entities = [scene.entities mutableCopy];
```

The `GameScene1` extends `GameScene`, and `GameScene.h` has properly declared this property. This is my (partial) `GameScene.h`:

```
@interface GameScene : SKScene <SKPhysicsContactDelegate>
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray<GKEntity *> *entities;
@end
```

My `GameScene1.h` is short and there are only couple of imports and it extends `GameScene`, like this:

```
@interface GameScene1 : GameScene
```

Do you know why the XCode won't acknowledge the `entities` property and assign it a value?

Answer (score 0):

You should subclass `GKScene` to access the property `entities` instead of `SKScene`:

```
@interface GameScene : GKScene <SKPhysicsContactDelegate>

@end
```